# Permissions changes repeatedly and randomly revoked

Tags: 2010, permissions

Until recently all users had access to some surveys in one of my sites. Suddenly their rights were revoked. I assumed someone had removed them accidentally (an issue for another time), so I added them back in. To my surprise 15 minutes later the users had been removed once again. This happens every time.

This leads me to another (related) question. I have set up site collection auditing to find out whats happening, however it only shows that something was changed, not who changed it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you setup the audit properly?

http://blog.sharepointedutech.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx

this is a free version (3rd party) it shows the users actions and more, you can check out the images... it goes into detail

http://www.netwrix.com/sharepoint_auditing.html

it can be alot of things that are causing the revoking of the permissios, do you know how often its causing the revoking, is it every 15 min? when did this start happening? whats new thats been added?

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at those links now. In answer to your questions at the bottom: I seemed to be every 10 minutes (ish). It only started this afternoon, about 2 hours ago, and now it seems to have mysteriously stopped. Nothing major has been changed in the site collection, and absolutely nothing has been changed on that specific site.